# What body part of goddess Sati fell on Dakshineswar Kali temple and Kalighat Kali temple?

Tags: temple, devi, kali, sati-goddess

What body part of goddess Sati fell on Dakshineswar Kali temple and Kalighat Kali temple of 20 km from each other?

Comment: the body of your question does not correspond to the title of your question. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Which is ur real question? the one in the body or the one in the title? both are entirely different questions. Pls edit to make it clear.

Comment: @YDS You should not change the question entirely without knowing what the actual question of the OP is. We don't know what is their original question. Don't d such edits which conflict witth OP's intent. That is the most important  thing. You should at least leave a comment and a reason what steps OP should take next as they are new to site. We should not edit as we wish.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma look at tags and Q body..the appropriate title was not chosen..It's better to make new user's Q more clear than closing it..

Comment: @YDS New users don't know how to tag questions or write questions on the first day itself. Those tags could be used for mantra question too. Just look at the tags. They are still wrong. We should know which question they want to ask first and then edit. Knowing their intent is important first. It's fine to put on hold because it doesn't take much effort to roepen again.

Comment: Sorry for the title as site didn't accepted mine 3 to 5 times.

Comment: Please make the title simple of 4 to 8 words as i'm new user. The main question is the body itself which I described in it.  Yea you can change the title these time. There is no reply button. It suitable for reply to clarify my title.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Kalighat temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalighat_Kali_Temple) region the fingers (some source says only 4 fingers) of Devi's right foot fell. Here the Devi is called Kalika and the Bhairava is called Nakuleswara.

Here is a relevant verse:

> Nakulishah kalipithe **dakshapadaanguli** cha me |
>  Sarvasiddhikari
>   devi kalika tatra devata ||

Source is one the Devi related books that I have. Same thing is stated in the hard copy  Panjika that I have too. I am not sure which scripture is the source of the above verse though.

Note- "Dakshapadanguli" means "fingers of the right foot".